# is a "Fusion" drive still usable after the flash portion fails?

Tags: macos, hardware-failure, fusion-drive

It seems like with a Fusion drive you now have two separate components that can fail.  The MTBF between the SSD part and the spinning part isn't going to be all that different, although the reason for failure is - for the SSD the failure is going to occur because of too much writing.  Since everything written to the spinning HD gets written to the SSD first (in addition to being pulled *back* to the SSD if frequently used), combined with the fact that the SSD is only about 1/4 or 1/8th the size of the HD, it seems like this would accelerate wear on the SSD.

So what happens when the SSD fails before the HD?  Obviously everything on the SSD is lost, but is the (spinning) drive still usable?  Or does an SSD failure make the whole drive unusable?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Seagate's implementation will continue to operate as a normal HDD if the flash component fails. However, It doesn't seem Fusion Drive will always place data on both SSD and HDD, which means data loss could occur. You might want to look at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bwDraco's comment intimates, the answer will depend on the manufacturer's implementation. These hybrid drives may use the SSD as the drive's cache; if this is how it is made then failure of the SSD will make the whole drive inaccessible. If, on the other hand, onboard firmware simply uses writeback to cache things on the drive to the SSD, then it may be that the SSD's failure will simply lead the computer to tell the drive to check the HDD, which it will. I say "may" because I can also imagine a scenario in which the firmware sees that data ought to reside on the SSD cache and doesn't have a way to find the older version still residing on the drive. In that case you could use something like testdisk to rescue the files on the HDD, but the drive might need to be reformatted before it was totally usable again. I'm also wondering what happens if the MFT of an NTFS partition is cached to the SSD when/if this happens.